# Python get the "self" of complete program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am programming a program with addon support. The addons are simple python scripts to import them

```
import addon1
import addon2
import addon3
myvar = "hello"
def myfunc():
    return "Python is great"
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = "Stackoverflow is great"
```

Now i want to access all variables from my program in the addons (i.e. addon1)

So i want to call the addon with my program as parameter (Like self in classes)

```
addon1.i_call_you(__program_self__)
```

So i search something similar to self in classes for complete python programs.

PS: For understanding:

```
addon1.py    

def i_call_you(prog):
    print(prog.myvar)
    prog.myfunc()
```

Comment: It should contain all variables and functions. (like self in classes)

Comment: The addons should import your module (the one with `myvar` and `myfunc`)

Comment: Maybe globals() is what you're looking for. It returns a dictionary but that should be no problem.

Comment: Can you explain globals() a bit, please?

Comment: The addons can't import the main module because the real program is a stand alone application which creates windows, etc. on startup

Comment: @palsch Yeah, it's globals()

Comment: Please enter this as an answer and i will upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in function

```
globals()
```

returns a dictionary with every global variable in it. That's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly what i was searching for ;)

Comment: PS: I used it for my quizmaker on quiz2015.lima-city.de

Comment: Looks great @Faminator

Comment: You can join the weekendhackers and present your project: weekendhacker.net -> Sign up and you'll get a link to the chat-app Slack

Comment: Thank you ;) Are you also at weekendhackers?

Comment: How can i invite you. My site is asapplications.slack.com

Comment: No you have to get invited by the weekendhackers

Comment: Okay and how can i do this?

Comment: Sign up on weekendhacker.net

Comment: And some time later you get an email with the invitation.

Comment: In my case it took about 1 hour.

Comment: A person sends the invitations, not a bot.

Comment: I didn't get one. Is there another way to get the mail?

Comment: I signed up 30 min ago

Comment: But we can chat without weekendhackers.

Comment: What's your slack-name?

Comment: My name is famecastle but my team name is asapplications

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92999/discussion-between-faminator-and-pal-sch).